# Why I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, datatables

I am start working with DataTable.js and when I want to integrate in my project which is done in ASP.NET CORE MVC 5.0 I get error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I try to google and I found that this error may come when you JQuery is older version, but I updated to newest version 3.7.1

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

WHat else I look is I  try to change calling of function to call by ID and by class but nothing change as well.
Here is my layout page as well where I include `datatable.min.js` and  `datatable.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - BergClinic</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/datatables/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/datatables/datatables.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/fontawesome/css/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-primary border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">BergClinic</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Patient" asp-action="Index">Patients</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Doctor" asp-action="Index">Doctors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="AdmissionPatient" asp-action="Index">Admission patient</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-white-50 bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - BergClinic
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/datatables/datatables.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>



    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In my Index View Page I also create calling of datatable in following meaner

```
@model IEnumerable<BergClinics.Models.Doctor>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="container p-3 bg-white">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Doctor's List</h2>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-doctor"  style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Doctor Name
                    </th>                   
                    <th>
                        Code
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Speciality
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var obj in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Firstname @obj.Lastname</td>                       
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Code</td>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Speciality</td>


                        <td class="text-center">
                            <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                <a asp-controller="Doctor" asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a asp-controller="Doctor" asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p> No Doctor exists.</p>
    }

</div>


<script>
    $('.datatable-doctor').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        //buttons: [
        //    {
        //        text: '<i class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Create New Doctor</a>',
        //        className: 'btn bg-blue',
        //        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        //            window.location.replace("/Doctor/Create");
        //        }
        //    }
        //],
        columnDefs: [

            //Ovaj dio je potreban
            {
                responsivePriority: 1,
                targets: -1
            },
            {
                targets: [0],
                orderable: true,
                searchable: true,
                printable: true,
                width: "120"
            }
        ]
    });

</script>
```

Does anyone know where I made mistake ? What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load jQuery you create a new instance of `$` and `jQuery` which **don't have any plugins** you had *previously* loaded and attached to previous instances of jQuery.

> ```
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
>       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

You are loading **four** different versions of jQuery!

Load **one** and make sure it is the **current** version.

Remove all of the lines quoted above except the first one.

---

You are trying to call `DataTables` in a script loaded in the body of the document, which is above the footer where you have:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/datatables/datatables.js"></script>
> ```

You need to load the plugin **before** you call it.

You also shouldn't load the plugin twice.

Move one of those lines so it is immediately after the line where you load jQuery. Remove the other one.

Comment: unfortunetlly, nothink happened. I remove all of this and just put one JQuery but still have problem !

Comment: No, still have problem. It seems like tha version of datatable or JQuery made problem